# Bash cd command autocompletion for custom alias

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, alias, cd

Let's say I have a simple function serving as an alias to `cd`.

`c(){ cd "$@"; }`

**How can I get the original autocompletion of** `cd` **work for my new function?** Note that `cd` only autocompletes directory names, not simple file names.

I know about the `complete` command, but where exactly is the autocompletion function used by `cd` located?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Look for `/etc/bash_completion` or `/etc/bash_completion.d` for the system-wide defaults.

Comment: Note that `cd` probably doesn't have any specific completions defined for it; rather, it uses some form of default completion provided by `bash` and/or `readline` for filename completion.